# How to send push notifications based on DB fields

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I have an app that uses a normal PhPMyAdmin database as the backend and all the interactions of the app with the DB happen via a PHP script.

Now I want to send push notifications to the user based on the Database. Let us say I have a separate DB (user name(s) , message to be sent).

Is there any service or script that will allow me to do what I want?

Or is there any other service (eg. Firebase) which allows me to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Before most of us use GCM for push notification but it is deprecated. I'm using FCM(firebase cloud messaging), it work amazing. You don't ever bother to look for GCM tutorial or guide anymore. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) will give you everything you need to setup for push notification. Beside if you decided to create push notification for ios FCM support too. If you want to create chat application use XMPP server instead.

There is some php code never mention in FCM doc. After you implement all your code in android, here is the php code you need to implement to post request to FCM server which FCM will handle it and push to all device based on the register token you provide.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
//$field is the parameter you will be sending to FCM server in order to let FCM know which device, and the message you need to send to. You will get a better understading after study the doc.
$fields = array(
             'priority' => "high",
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'data' => $data
            );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key = 'your authorization key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
```

You will find a bit confuse how FCM work but eventually you will get used to it.